# How would I go about generating cities and countries with perlin noise?

Tags: python, noise

recently I made a little program that generates a country with a bit of info, like the country name, size and most importantly cities.

It generates a random number of cities and towns and villages based on the country's size, this is all text based so that is why I would give it a nice flare with some graphics.

Now, I have been researching a bit and it seems that my best option would be Perlin noise or some form of noise, so my question is, how would I go about doing this? Where do I start? Are there other ways of accomplishing this?

So, in short, how do I take the randomly generated text cities and towns and villages in my program and randomly generate them on some form of map? I hope this all makes sense. Also, my program is written in python.

Comment: Take a look at [FantasyMapGenerator](https://github.com/rlguy/FantasyMapGenerator)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I'll take a look at it it looks cool, but I wanna try my hand at making my own map thing with python. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: But I will check it out and try to learn something from it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of problem in what you saying. What platform are you using? Arcade? PyGame? etc. I will write the arcade code for you so you can use. To use arcade, type `pip install arcade` in Windows, or `pip3 install arcade` on Linux.

Edit:

Please can you post your code so I can implement?

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, I will do that.

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker Should I code for you? Or you will do:)

Comment: Hello sorry for the late response, I'm busy getting my code ready, also no you don't have to get for me, because then I would feel very bad for wasting your time on something not that important and I would feel bad that i didn't do it myself, but I would appreciate it if you coded a little bit just so that I have something to work with :)

Comment: Here is my code, it is split up into three files: #1 The main generation process: https://pastebin.com/9XeXuVvQ               #2. The info for the generation process: https://pastebin.com/6qbJM2sL              and #3. The main.py file: https://pastebin.com/GsbJpFzS

Comment: Thank you very much for volunteering to help me, kind stranger.

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker Ok, thanks, I'll work on it now! I will also make some code to generate the precise dimensions in pixels, depending on whether it is a large, medium or small country.

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker We will also have to limit the max number of countries, as we will have to render every single town/city/village.

Comment: @Keenonthedaywalker I am almost done. I will share source code as soon as possible.

Comment: There's no rush :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231401/discussion-between-sergei-kiselev-and-keenonthedaywalker).